# Dynamic component click event in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I render Vue components using `v-for`:

```
<component
    v-for="component in components"
    :is="component.type"
    @click="myFunction(component.id)">
</component>
```

Clicking on the rendered component doesn't fire the `myFunction` method. However, clicking a manually inserted component does:

```
<div @click="myFunction('...')"></div>
```

How to correct this?

Answer (score 11):

Add the .native modifier to listen for a native event instead of a component event.

```
<component
    v-for="component in components"
    :is="component.type"
    @click.native="myFunction(component.id)">
</component>
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the click handler as a prop to the child component, for instance:

```
<component
   v-for="component in components"
   :is="component.type"
   :on-click="myFunction.bind(this, component.id)">
</component>

// Component
<template>
  <button @click="onClick">Click me</button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['onClick']
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
<template v-for="component in components">
  <component :is="component.type" @click="myFunction(component.id)" />
</template >
```

Comment: The `@click` binding needs to be on the div but otherwise this works. Why is that? This creates unnecessary elements in the DOM.

Comment: @Mikko  I have modified the answer, which should not add unnecessary elements in the DOM.

Comment: Binding the click event to the template tag doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you are trying to do is not needed or correct. If you want to call a function defined in the parent whenever the child component is clicked you can just wrap the component in an element and bind the event to that wrapper. That way the function will fire whenever you click whichever component is rendered inside it and you'll have not events bound directly to components

```
<div class="wrapper" v-for="component in components" @click="myFunction(component.id)">
    <component :is="component.type"/>
</div>
```

That should do it.